# Populate cells with numbers

Tags: excel, populate

**I have a numerical value say n in A1.
 I want to populate column B from B1 starting from 1 to n.
Suppose if A1 is 240, then B1 should be 1, B2 should be 2, and so on till B240 is 240. How can this be done?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Select all of column B and type in,**

**`=IF(ROW()<=A1, ROW(), TEXT(,))`**

**Hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter all together, not just Enter alone.**

Comment: The formula worked. Since I wanted a header row, I modified your logic and made it as follows
=IF(ROW()<=$A$1+1, ROW()-1, TEXT(,))

Comment: If a graph has to be plotted with the elements in B1 to Bn as X-axis values, how can I choose not to include those values which are not in B1 cells in the graph?
For example, if B1 to B10 contains 1 to 10 sequentially, the graph should have only B1 to B10. I have given the X-axis data range as B1 to B240 (as 240 is the maximum value which is allowed). When the graph is plotted, the values from B1 to B10 are visible in graph but from 11 to 240 are not shown and hence the graph looks compressed. I want to eliminate the spaces in the graph from 11 to 240 so that graph looks appealing.

Comment: That would appear to be another question. Sorry to be stubborn, but the followup really deserves an independent inquiry.